# Can you delete a specific sheet without knowing sheet ID?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have code which does the following:

1. Collects values from first sheet "OTW Sheet"
2. Opens another existing sheet by Id - "Invoice"
3. Sets values in "Invoice" as copied from "OTW Sheet"
4. Creates a new spreadsheet in the Drive App and copies "Invoice" to new Spreadsheet.

This all works well but the next step is to delete the sheet called "Sheet1" in the newly created Spreadsheet. This part I can't get to work. No errors appear, it just fails to delete the sheet.

Code is as follows:

```js
function myFunction() {
  
  var orderSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("OTW Sheet");
  var row = OrderSheet.getLastRow();
  var values1 = OrderSheet.getRange(row, 5).getValue();
  var cost1 = OrderSheet.getRange(1, 16).getValue();

  var invoice = SpreadsheetApp.openById("19wv72wCNsPV6_hK8XCRcMBkfzEEU1IrJB6scuPz2Vfo"); 
  invoice.getSheetByName("BLANK");
  
  var newsheet = Invoice.getActiveSheet();
  newsheet.getRange(17, 7).setValue(cost1);
  newsheet.getRange(1, 15).setValue(values1);

  var newSS = SpreadsheetApp.create('OTW Invoice'); 
  newsheet.copyTo(NewSS).setName('OTW Invoice ' + cost1).getSheetId();
  var folder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("TEST Invoices").next();
  var copyFile = DriveApp.getFileById(newSS.getId());
  folder.addFile(CopyFile);

  newSS.getId();
  SpreadsheetApp.openById(NewSS).getSheetByName("Sheet1").deleteSheet();
}
```

Comment: Why can't you get the id of the spreadsheet?  If you are asking about a component of class Sheet then you only need the name because all sheets have to have unique names

Comment: Because it has only just been created and i want the script to run my functions in 1 go i can;t get it manually. And `getId` doesn't seem to be doing what I want it to.

Comment: Yes but NewSS.getId() get's you the id

Comment: If your code is not working then please provide [mcve] and I'll get it working for you.  Please read the requirements for [mcve]  I don't wish to have a long piece of code I just need the portion that you are asking about and the part that reproduces the issue that you wish to address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
  NewSS.getId();
  SpreadsheetApp.openById(NewSS).getSheetByName("Sheet1").deleteSheet();
```

by

```
NewSS.deleteSheet(NewSS.getSheetByName("Sheet1"));
```

Reference

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#deletesheetsheet

Answer (score 1):

#### Deleting A Sheet of a newly created spreadsheet

This works:

```
function myFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ssid");
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const nss = SpreadsheetApp.create('OTW Invoice');
  sh.copyTo(nss).setName('OTW Invoice ' + ' Copy');
  const fldr = DriveApp.getFoldersByName("TestFolder").next();//assume only one
  const file = DriveApp.getFileById(nss.getId());
  fldr.addFile(file);//move nss to a subfolder
  nss.deleteSheet(nss.getSheetByName("Sheet1"));
}
```